# No rule to make target `scripts/extract-cert' when building Linux Kernel - Centos 7, devtoolset-9

Tags: centos, linux-kernel, compiling, openssl, ld

I'm trying to debug my build environment for compiling a linux kernel with some patch sets.

I installed devtoolset-9 in my CentOS 7 environment to satisfy the minimum gcc version requirement of the 5.15.86 linux kernel branch. When compiling the kernel with a simple `make bzImage`, I get the following error:

```
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `scripts/extract-cert', needed by `certs/x509_certificate_list'.  Stop.
```

I then tried to make extract-cert by cd'ing to scripts and running `make extract-cert`, but get the following error:

```
    cc     extract-cert.c   -o extract-cert
/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/9/ld: /tmp/ccx32b6d.o: in function `display_openssl_errors':
extract-cert.c:(.text+0x3e): undefined reference to `ERR_peek_error'
/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/9/ld: extract-cert.c:(.text+0x7f): undefined reference to `ERR_error_string'
/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/9/ld: extract-cert.c:(.text+0xc2): undefined reference to `ERR_get_error_line'
/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/9/ld: /tmp/ccx32b6d.o: in function `drain_openssl_errors':
extract-cert.c:(.text+0xdd): undefined reference to `ERR_peek_error'
/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/9/ld: extract-cert.c:(.text+0xf6): undefined reference to `ERR_get_error_line'
/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/9/ld: /tmp/ccx32b6d.o: in function `write_cert':
extract-cert.c:(.text+0x132): undefined reference to `BIO_new_file'
/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/9/ld: extract-cert.c:(.text+0x186): undefined reference to `X509_get_subject_name'
/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/9/ld: extract-cert.c:(.text+0x1a0): undefined reference to `X509_NAME_oneline'
/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/9/ld: extract-cert.c:(.text+0x1b9): undefined reference to `i2d_X509_bio'
/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/9/ld: /tmp/ccx32b6d.o: in function `main':
extract-cert.c:(.text+0x230): undefined reference to `OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_noconf'
/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/9/ld: extract-cert.c:(.text+0x235): undefined reference to `ERR_load_crypto_strings'
/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/9/ld: extract-cert.c:(.text+0x23a): undefined reference to `ERR_clear_error'
/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/9/ld: extract-cert.c:(.text+0x338): undefined reference to `ENGINE_load_builtin_engines'
/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/9/ld: extract-cert.c:(.text+0x347): undefined reference to `ENGINE_by_id'
/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/9/ld: extract-cert.c:(.text+0x386): undefined reference to `ENGINE_init'
/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/9/ld: extract-cert.c:(.text+0x3e2): undefined reference to `ENGINE_ctrl_cmd_string'
/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/9/ld: extract-cert.c:(.text+0x437): undefined reference to `ENGINE_ctrl_cmd'
/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/9/ld: extract-cert.c:(.text+0x48a): undefined reference to `BIO_new_file'
/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/9/ld: extract-cert.c:(.text+0x4df): undefined reference to `PEM_read_bio_X509'
/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/9/ld: extract-cert.c:(.text+0x4fb): undefined reference to `ERR_peek_last_error'
/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/9/ld: extract-cert.c:(.text+0x522): undefined reference to `ERR_clear_error'
/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/9/ld: extract-cert.c:(.text+0x57a): undefined reference to `BIO_free'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [extract-cert] Error 1
```

I searched in the OpenSSL source code on [github](https://github.com/openssl/openssl) and found the symbols that the linker is complaining about. So it seems that it is an OpenSSL error. I have OpenSSL installed, but I'm not sure how it works with devtoolset-9. How do I get the linker within devtoolset-9 to find the OpenSSL library? The pkgconfig files look correct to me, and the libraries exist in /usr/lib64/

```
$>gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 9.3.1 20200408 (Red Hat 9.3.1-2) Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc. This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017

$>yum list installed | grep ssl
openssl.x86_64                          1:1.0.2k-26.el7_9        @updates
openssl-devel.x86_64                    1:1.0.2k-26.el7_9        @updates
openssl-libs.x86_64                     1:1.0.2k-26.el7_9        @updates

$>find . -name 'libssl*'
./usr/lib64/pkgconfig/libssl.pc
./usr/lib64/libssl.so.1.0.2k
./usr/lib64/libssl.so.10
./usr/lib64/libssl3.so
./usr/lib64/libssl.so

$>cat ./usr/lib64/pkgconfig/libssl.pc
prefix=/usr
exec_prefix=${prefix}
libdir=${exec_prefix}/lib64
includedir=${prefix}/include

Name: OpenSSL-libssl
Description: Secure Sockets Layer and cryptography libraries
Version: 1.0.2k
Requires: libcrypto
Libs: -L${libdir} -lssl
Libs.private: -ldl -lz -lgssapi_krb5 -lkrb5 -lcom_err -lk5crypto
Cflags: -I${includedir} -I/usr/include

$>cat ./usr/lib64/pkgconfig/libcrypto.pc
prefix=/usr
exec_prefix=${prefix}
libdir=${exec_prefix}/lib64
includedir=${prefix}/include
enginesdir=/usr/lib64/openssl/engines

Name: OpenSSL-libcrypto
Description: OpenSSL cryptography library
Version: 1.0.2k
Requires:
Libs: -L${libdir} -lcrypto
Libs.private: -ldl -lz
Cflags: -I${includedir}
```

**@Ginnungagap:** The result of `echo | gcc -xc -E -v -` is:

```
$> echo | gcc -xc -E -v -
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --enable-bootstrap --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,lto --prefix=/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr --mandir=/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/share/man --infodir=/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --enable-multilib --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --with-gcc-major-version-only --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=gcc4-compatible --enable-plugin --enable-initfini-array --with-isl=/builddir/build/BUILD/gcc-9.3.1-20200408/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux/isl-install --disable-libmpx --enable-gnu-indirect-function --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=x86-64 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 9.3.1 20200408 (Red Hat 9.3.1-2) (GCC)
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-E' '-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/9/cc1 -E -quiet -v - -mtune=generic -march=x86-64
ignoring nonexistent directory "/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/9/include-fixed"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/9/../../../../x86_64-redhat-linux/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/9/include
 /usr/local/include
 /opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/include
 /usr/include
End of search list.
# 1 "<stdin>"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 31 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 32 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "<stdin>"
COMPILER_PATH=/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/9/:/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/9/:/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/:/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/9/:/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/
LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/9/:/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/9/../../../../lib64/:/lib/../lib64/:/usr/lib/../lib64/:/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/9/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-E' '-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
```

Comment: If I run gcc manually using the below command from the `scripts` directory, extract-cert compiles fine:
`gcc -L /usr/lib64 -l ssl -l crypto extract-cert.c -o extract-cert`
However, compiling the kernel from the root directory then results in this error:
`make[3]: *** No rule to make target 'crypto/asymmetric_keys/x509.asn1.c', needed by 'crypto/asymmetric_keys/x509.asn1.o'.  Stop.`

Comment: Please format output as code and not as quote to avoid line wrapping.

Comment: @Ginnungagap Done!

Comment: Can you post the result of `echo | gcc -xc -E -v -` (from [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6666338)).

Comment: @Ginnungagap I appended the output to my question, since it was too long for a comment.

Comment: According to the [OpenSSL](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_0_2k/crypto/err/err.h#L325), the definition for `ERR_peek_error` is in `openssl/err.h` which is properly included by [scripts/extract-cert.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v5.15/scripts/extract-cert.c). The include path contains `/usr/include` which should contain the openssl headers, maybe verify with `rpm -ql openssl-devel | grep err.h`?

Comment: @Ginnungagap Thank you. Yes, you are right, openssl/err.h is in openssl-devel:
`$> rpm -ql openssl-devel | grep err.h
/usr/include/openssl/err.h`
I only saw the linking error when I tried to make extract-cert directly from the scripts directory. I wonder if that's the wrong approach. From the root kernel directory, running make resulted in `No rule to make target scripts/extract-cert'`. How can I troubleshoot why make thinks there is no rule for it? Since it seems to find the rule when running make from the scripts subdirectory directly....

Answer (score 0):

This issue was due to a broken Makefile at scripts/Makefile. I was cherry-picking a custom patch from an older kernel version, and at some point the new kbuild shorthand hostprogs-**always**-y was introduced. When I cherry-picked the old patch, this was changed back to just hostprogs-y. This caused the helper programs in scripts/* not to get built by kbuild.

Example Makefile entry for extract-cert:

```
hostprogs-always-$(CONFIG_SYSTEM_TRUSTED_KEYRING)   += extract-cert
```

Information from patchwork is [here](https://patchwork.kernel.org/project/linux-kbuild/patch/20200801122718.543376-1-masahiroy@kernel.org/).

Quoting the patch from Masahiro Yamada:

> To build host programs, you need to add the program names to
> 'hostprogs' to use the necessary build rule, but it is not enough to
> build them because there is no dependency.
>
> There are two types of host programs: built as the prerequisite of
> another (e.g. gen_crc32table in lib/Makefile), or always built when
> Kbuild visits the Makefile (e.g. genksyms in
> scripts/genksyms/Makefile).
>
> The latter is typical in Makefiles under scripts/, which contains host
> programs globally used during the kernel build. To build them, you
> need to add them to both 'hostprogs' and 'always-y'.
>
> This commit adds hostprogs-always-y as a shorthand.

Answer (score -1):

extract-certs was moved from scripts/ to certs/ from kernel 5.17 [commit](https://github.com/gregkh/linux/commit/340a02535ee785c64c62a9c45706597a0139e972)

i suppose the make target must be updated